# How to define Firewall access for Power BI Services to Azure SQL?

Tags: powerbi, azure-sql-database

I have currently Power BI service (dynamic IP)
I need let access to Azure SQL.
What IP should be added to allowed IP list?

What is best practise?

Comment: Is your Azure sql database hosted within a vnet? Or is it normal controlled by Azure server firewall?

Comment: You must configure the [Azure Firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/service-tags) to allow [`PowerBI` service tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/service-tags-overview).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using public access, then enable `Allow Azure services and resources to access this server` in networking tab of Sql server

[image]

And add firewall rule with start IP `0.0.0.0` end IP `255.255.255.255`

[image]

It will allow all without whitelisting the IP addresses. If you are using private endpoint as @Andrey Nikolov said add the Power BI service tag to the allowed IP list in your Azure SQL firewall rules. This allows any IP address associated with the Power BI service to access Azure SQL database. for service tags you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/service-tags-overview).
When following above procedure Azure Sql database is connecting automatically without mentioning of IP address.

[image]

[image]